# Move current object on iterator to end of list

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

I'm having a problem on Java using Iterator (LinkedList.iterator()) object. In a looping, I need move a iterator object from some place to end of list.

For instance:

```
final Iterator<Transition> it = this.transitions.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    final Transition object = it.next();

    if(object.id == 3){
        // Move to end of this.transitions list
        // without throw ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

I can't clone this.transitions for some reasons. It's possible, or I really need use the clone method?

**Edit**: currently, I do it:

```
        it.remove();
        this.transitions.add(object);
```

But the problem is just on this second line. I can't add itens, it I'm inner an iterator of the same object. :(

Comment: Have you tried it?  I'm pretty sure you can modify `this.transitions` without any problems because you're not looping on it directly, you're using an `Iterator`, which is basically a clone of `this.transitions`.

Comment: Yeah. `it.remove()` works perfectly on remotion. But the problem is add to end of list by use `this.transitions.add(object)` method.

Comment: Oh, you mean when you add it at the end it doesn't come up in the `Iterator`?

Comment: When I add on end of list it throw the `ConcurrentModificationException`, because the `this.transition` is "locked" for modifications.

Comment: @jonah no he means that the fail-fast behavior of the iterator is stopping him from doing what he wants

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can keep a second list of elements to be added:

```
final Iterator<Transition> it = this.transitions.iterator();
final List<Transition> tmp = new ArrayList();//using a list will keep the order
while(it.hasNext()) {
    final Transition object = it.next();

    if(object.id == 3){
        it.remove();
        tmp.add(object);
    }
}
this.transitions.addAll(tmp);
```

Comment: Yeah. It is the unique way that I think too. I'll accept you answer in a minute. If exists other way (without make a new variable or clone) will be welcome. But only for work already better than before. hehe thanks